# Symfony en laragon

Tags: symfony, laragon

he creado un proyecto Symfony con el creador de sitios de laragon pero desde el terminal no reconoce nada, seguro lo estoy haciendo mal pero no sé cómo iniciarlo, tengo todo el árbol de directorios que ha generado, en principio bien, pero no consigo hacer el server:start, dice que no reconoce el comando Symfony.

Alguien me puede echar una mano?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Necesita instalar la herramienta Symfony CLI.